# How to use matplotlib/seaborn to create figure with n x n columns and rows with major top and side titles

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
id         a1    a2     a3    a4    a5    a6   value1     value2
 1         .2    .3    .4     .2   .1     .2     1         0
 2         .1    .2    .1     .3   .7     .3     1         1
 3         .4    .1    .1     .1   .5     .4     0         0
 4         .5    .3    .3     .4   .6     .1     0         1
 5         .3    .1    .1     .3   .2     .3     0         1
 6         .7    .2    .3     .3   .6     .1     0         0
 7         .2    .6    .8     .1   .2     .4     1         1
 8         .1    .4    .2     .1   .9     .3     0         1
 9         .4    .2    .1     .3   .5     .2     1         0
 
cols = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
titles = []

for x in cols:
    
    g = sns.lmplot(x = x,
           y = 'value1', 
           data = data,
           scatter_kws={"color": "black"}, line_kws={"color": "blue"})

    title = x + 'val1'
    g.set(title = title)
    titles.append(title)

    g = sns.lmplot(x = x,
                   y = 'value2', 
                   data = data,
                   scatter_kws={"color": "black"}, line_kws={"color": "blue"})
    title = x + 'val2'
    g.set(title = title)
    titles.append(title)
```

I want to create a figure that has all 8 plots in a 4 by 2 column but there is text on top of the columns and text to the right of each plot. Like so:

[image: plot]
I have tried using

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(3, 2)

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
```

But I don't know how to incorporate this with the code I am using to generate the plots.

Comment: What do you want the text on the top and left side to be? Seaborn can handle it if you arrrange them as columns.

Comment: Say column 1 is "% of value1" and column 2 is '% of value2 ". Same with the 'fig..' text. That is not the actual text but just a placeholder. They will each be different otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create one figure from plot results of for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526252/how-to-create-one-figure-from-plot-results-of-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

By [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)ing your DataFrame twice you can get the [long-form shape](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) for `lmplot`:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

s = StringIO(
    """id         a1    a2     a3    a4    a5    a6   value1     value2
 1         .2    .3    .4     .2   .1     .2     1         0
 2         .1    .2    .1     .3   .7     .3     1         1
 3         .4    .1    .1     .1   .5     .4     0         0
 4         .5    .3    .3     .4   .6     .1     0         1
 5         .3    .1    .1     .3   .2     .3     0         1
 6         .7    .2    .3     .3   .6     .1     0         0
 7         .2    .6    .8     .1   .2     .4     1         1
 8         .1    .4    .2     .1   .9     .3     0         1
 9         .4    .2    .1     .3   .5     .2     1         0
 """
)
df = pd.read_csv(s, sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
data = df.melt(
    id_vars=["id", "value1", "value2"],
    value_vars=["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"],
    value_name="a_val",
    var_name="a_var",
).melt(
    id_vars=["id", "a_val", "a_var"],
    value_vars=["value1", "value2"],
    value_name="value",
    var_name="variable",
)
```

Then we can plot the whole figure in one go:

```py
grid = sns.lmplot(
    data=data,
    x="a_val",
    y="value",
    row="a_var",
    col="variable",
    scatter_kws={"color": "black"},
    line_kws={"color": "blue"},
)
```

[image: lmplot facetgrid]