# How to create one figure from plot results of for loop

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
id         a1    a2     a3    a4    a5    a6   value1     value2
 1         .2    .3    .4     .2   .1     .2     1         0
 2         .1    .2    .1     .3   .7     .3     1         1
 3         .4    .1    .1     .1   .5     .4     0         0
 4         .5    .3    .3     .4   .6     .1     0         1
 5         .3    .1    .1     .3   .2     .3     0         1
 6         .7    .2    .3     .3   .6     .1     0         0
 7         .2    .6    .8     .1   .2     .4     1         1
 8         .1    .4    .2     .1   .9     .3     0         1
 9         .4    .2    .1     .3   .5     .2     1         0
 
cols = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
titles = []

for x in cols:
    
    g = sns.lmplot(x = x,
           y = 'value1', 
           data = data,
           scatter_kws={"color": "black"}, line_kws={"color": "blue"})

    title = x + 'val1'
    g.set(title = title)
    titles.append(title)
    plt.show()


    g = sns.lmplot(x = x,
                   y = 'value2', 
                   data = data,
                   scatter_kws={"color": "black"}, line_kws={"color": "blue"})
    title = x + 'val2'
    g.set(title = title)
    titles.append(title)
    plt.show()
```

This shows me each figure under each other. I want to create a figure that has all 8 plots in a 4 by 2 column but there is text on top of the columns and text to the right of each plot. Like so:

[image: plot]
I have tried using

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(3, 2)

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
```

Ideally, I am looking for the plots with the title and side labvels. But just the figure with plots would be great. But I don't know how to incorporate this with the code I am using to generate the plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an [`lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) for the complete dataframe, the data needs to be in [long form](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data). As there are two sets of columns, [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) needs to be called twice, taking care the columns of melted dataframe get different names.  These names will then be used for the `col` and `row` of the created [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).

The code below chooses `fig` and `ai` for the melted columns of `a1`..`a6`. And `val` and `value` for the melted version of `value1` and `value2`. You 'll probably want to choose different names, consistent with how you want to present your data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''id         a1    a2     a3    a4    a5    a6   value1     value2
 1         .2    .3    .4     .2   .1     .2     1         0
 2         .1    .2    .1     .3   .7     .3     1         1
 3         .4    .1    .1     .1   .5     .4     0         0
 4         .5    .3    .3     .4   .6     .1     0         1
 5         .3    .1    .1     .3   .2     .3     0         1
 6         .7    .2    .3     .3   .6     .1     0         0
 7         .2    .6    .8     .1   .2     .4     1         1
 8         .1    .4    .2     .1   .9     .3     0         1
 9         .4    .2    .1     .3   .5     .2     1         0'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
df1 = df.melt(value_vars=['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6'], var_name='fig', value_name='ai',
              id_vars=['value1', 'value2'])
df2 = df1.melt(value_vars=['value1', 'value2'], var_name='val', value_name='value', id_vars=['fig', 'ai'])

g = sns.lmplot(x='ai',
               y='value',
               row='fig',  # 'value1', 'value2'
               col='val',  # 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6'
               height=1.3,
               aspect=4,
               data=df2,
               scatter_kws={"color": "black"}, line_kws={"color": "blue"}, )
g.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.06, bottom=0.06)  # a bit more space for the labels
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lmplot on melted dataframe]

The melted dataframe looks like:

```
    fig   ai     val  value
0    a1  0.2  value1      1
1    a1  0.1  value1      1
2    a1  0.4  value1      0
3    a1  0.5  value1      0
4    a1  0.3  value1      0
..   ..  ...     ...    ...
103  a6  0.3  value2      1
104  a6  0.1  value2      0
105  a6  0.4  value2      1
106  a6  0.3  value2      1
107  a6  0.2  value2      0
```

Comment: I've given an almost identical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525148/how-to-use-matplotlib-seaborn-to-create-figure-with-n-x-n-columns-and-rows-with)  This is better though, much more thorough explanation!